# warning: unable to access D:\/.config/git/config': Permission denied

Tags: git

I am unable to pull/push code to/from my git repo. Getting the following error: warning: unable to access .config/git/config': Permission denied

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by adding a new environment variable: HOME and assigning it the value C:\

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding a new "HOME" system environment variable and pointing it to the directory in which my codebase resides e.g. C:\